# Problem with occupied port 8080 under Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, port

I have a strange problem. The port 8080 on my Windows XP machine is busy. When I do

```
telnet localhost 8080
```

I am getting connected to something, however when I use netstat

```
netstat -aon | find "8080"
```

I get no result.

I tried to use TCPView, no success - it shows no results.

I tried to use nmap. This time I've got result:

> 8080/tcp  unknown http-proxy for (port, state, service)

I am not using any proxy, at least I haven't switched on anything like this by myself.

The problem has appeared today, yesterday the port was not busy. I have restarted computer several times, but the problem persists. I use a lot of software, recently I have

Does anyone has any idea what process/program can use that port or how to check what is going on? Why netstat fails to show what process is using that port?

Answer (score 4):

Netstat and other tools might fail to display something if your system has been compromised.

If your system has been compromised then it is possible that no tool will be identify what is going on while the system is booted, and you may need to run a scan from a livecd.